# Delete files with same extension

Tags: windows, file, directory, windows-10, delete-file

Actually I wanted to remove all files having the same extension not only from the folder but also from the system.I want to delete files having same extensions from the whole hard disk

Comment: What method do you want to use, programs, languages, etc?

Comment: I would do anything for removing files with same extension cause i have to remove  ransomware files and they are .meds files i want to remove all files havig .meds extension from my entire hard disk and as far as possible It would be great if i can get that kind of program that removes files with the same extension from the hard disk if there is any program or replicated method please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that you delete ransomware files with this extension as you will lose your data PERMENANTLY. I recommend you look for a solution instead. Try connect this company, they have solutions for some ransom viruses.

[WiRE Microsystems](https://www.wiremicrosystems.com)